# Problem with upload FileField and ImageField in new django 3.0.4

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-3.0

I'm with a big issue about **django 3.0.4.** I'm using virtualenv with **python3.6.9** and **django==3.0.4**, In my models at upload process the picture be saved in correct folder, but return **error 500 on server** and the data field (title, category, file_attach) aren't saved in database. If I change django to version==2.2 in virtualenv the picture be stored and save in database without errors. Some bug or hack in django==3.0.4? The project was created in django 3 but work fine in 2.2. Some solution?

[image: Traceback]

Comment: Please check if setting [`FILE_UPLOAD_PERMISSIONS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#file-upload-permissions) solves this for you. Before django 3.0, the default value used to be None but now it has a default value.

Comment: @AKS thanks for help, but not working even 0o777

Comment: Please set it to `None` first to emulate the old behavior and check if it works.

Comment: @AKS wowwww it's working fine now! Thak you so much. Why? can you explain me?